# Handling a numerical value that may be specific or a range in a REST API

Tags: rest, api, api-design, json

Let's say I have a REST API that needs to return the width of an object, but that width may either be a specific value or a range of values. What would be the best practice for designing the API to handle this?

For example:

```
"width": 35.5
```

```
"width": {
  "minimum": 34.2,
  "maximum": 36.8
}
```

Would it be best to simply specify the same value as minimum and maximum?

```
"width": {
  "minimum": 35.5,
  "maximum": 35.5
}
```

Or use a different label (such as "width_range") for a range and only return one or the other?

Comment: Would this depend on the "type" of the object?

Comment: @StefanRendevski No, unfortunately; there is a mix of "types," but the odd object that has a range instead of a specific value may belong to any of them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This may very well depend on how your API is to be used, and how the "width" property of these objects is consumed, so without knowing specifics, I can only give a general recommendation.

I would suggest that you make the possible difference in the type of width explicit, by exposing a custom `Width` type, for example, with the following structure:

```
"width": {
  "type": "exact",
  "value": 35.5
}

"width": {
  "type": "range",
  "value": {
    "minimum": 34.2,
    "maximum": 36.8
  }
}
```

This would allow clients of your API to then also create an explicit `Width` type, and a corresponding class hierarchy, and work with that abstraction with specific implementations, in case client code has to work with these values in some way.

This could *technically* be accomplished by inspecting the type of "width" as per the example in your question, but from my perspective, it is easier to rely on an explicit enumeration, rather than the data type of the property itself.

Comment: For my use case client code will almost definitely need to work with the ranges, so this explicitness is an excellent solution. Thanks.